# Recipes to implement custom calls in a Backbone.Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a custom collection, called `SyncingCollection`, that extends `Backbone.Collection`. A collection has a custom model called `SyncingModel`.

The collection (once fetched) is displayed into a list. Each list item (represented by a model) can be removed (or saved) from the list. For example, the deletion process is a two steps phase:

1. Verify request to the service
2. Check the response
3. Deletion request (the model and the list item will be then removed if the service returns a `true` response)

I'm thinking to achieve a similar scenario by overriding the `destroy` model of a `Backbone.Model` component. Is this a correct approach? I suppose yes, but how to implement the `verify` request? Can I override a particular method? Any pattern to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would investigate overriding the model's `sync` method (see http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-141). Per the docs:

> The sync function may be overriden globally as Backbone.sync, or at a
>   finer-grained level, by adding a sync function to a Backbone
>   collection or to an individual model.

Check the `method` parameter: if it's "delete", verify the request, then either delete it here via another request or by delegating to `Backbone.sync`

If the method isn't "delete", simply proxy the call to `Backbone.sync`.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the reply. To summarize do you suggest to override the `sync` method and put a `if-else` logic there or do I have to maintain `sync` and `destroy` calls (where `sync` is used for the verify request)?

Comment: If would add a `sync` method on the model with if/else, and proxy to `Backbone.sync` if the method isn't "delete". That way you can continue using the model as normal (i.e. just call `destroy` and the validation will happen before).